# complex regular expression for angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, angular, vue.js

I want a regular expression which validates my input e.g "S19/999999/090". my input field should accept this kind of input. means the first character should be an uppercase alphabet from A-Z after that two digits from 0-9. after that one backslash. after that 6 digits from 0-9 after that one backslash. after that 3 digits from 0-9.

E.g "S19/999999/090"

I don't understand how to create this kind of regular expression.
Thank you in advance

Comment: ^[A-Z][\d]{2}\/[\d]{6}\/[\d]{3}$

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I use this all the time for experiments https://regexr.com/ try it

Answer (score 3):

check the attached fiddle. [https://regex101.com/r/IQsyv2/1/]

and regex will be like -

> ^[A-Z][\d]{2}/[\d]{6}/[\d]{3}$

here initially to notice I have specified ^ and $ these char are used to define the full length match, mean ^ - says starting and $ says ending.

```
[A-Z]  - mean check uppercase only once.

[\d]{2}  - mean [\d] any digit, {2} - 2 times

\/  -- mean match backslash

[\d]{6} - only digit 6 times exactly.

\/  -- mean match backslash

[\d]{3} - only digit 3 times exactly.
```

Comment: if it solved your problem, pls accept it as an answer to help others to locate the solution fast..

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[A-Z]\d{2}\/\d{6}\/\d{3}
```

[A-Z] - one character A-Z uppercase

\d - digital

\d{n} - n digital

/\ - /